# How can I transform a Laravel requested object from a query to int

Tags: php, laravel

i'm obtaining a whole object from the database using a Laravel query and an array with a simple query (see the following image)

```
public function editgamemenu($id){
    $game = Game::find($id);
    $genres = Genre::all();
    $selectedgenres = DB::table('game_genre')->select('genre_id')->where('game_id','=',$id)->get()->toArray();

    returnview('editgametext')>with(compact('game','genres','selectedgenres'));

}
```

After that i'm using a foreach to iterate around the object to try to see if the object's id is inside the array I extracted earlier but it gives you the following error: "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int"
Heres the view code:

```
<input type="hidden" value="{{$game->id}}" id="id" name="id">
<div class="form-group col-4">
  <p><strong>Genres:</strong></p>
  <div class="container">
  @foreach($genres as $genre)
    <span class="genre-list">
      <label>{{$genre->name}}</label>
      @if(in_array($genre,$selectedgenres))
      <input type="checkbox" name="genres[]" value="{{$genre->id}}" checked>
      @else
      <input type="checkbox" name="genres[]" value="{{$genre->id}}">

      @endif
    </span>
  @endforeach
```

I have already tried to cast the $genre->id into int but it doesnt work and some more stuff.
Help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: are you sure that you get error there?

Comment: Your first image link is broken

Comment: Please post your code, not screenshot of your code

Comment: I get the error on the @if condition of the second picture, yes i'm pretty sure . Already changed the images into code, sorry new here

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$selectedgenres = DB::table('game_genre')
    ->select('genre_id')
    ->where('game_id','=',$id)
    ->get()
    ->toArray();
```

To this

```
$selectedgenres = DB::table('game_genre')
    ->select('genre_id')
    ->where('game_id','=',$id)
    ->get()
    ->pluck('genre_id')
    ->toArray();
```

notice `->pluck('genre_id')`

Without the pluck, You will have an array of objects.

Edit: As @quickSwap noticed, in your blade file, you also need to change `$genre` to `$genre->id`

```
@if(in_array($genre->id, $selectedgenres))
    ....
@endif
```

Edit 2: You can also take advantages of `Collection`

```
$selectedgenres = DB::table('game_genre')
    ->where('game_id','=',$id)
    ->pluck('genre_id'); // returns a collection
```

And in your blade

```
@if($selectedgenres->contains($genre->id))
```

Comment: I convert pluck into array now it will work. Anyway for your method +1.

Answer (score 1):

You have problem here,

You need to use pluck to fetch only genre ids as below

```
$selectedgenres = DB::table('game_genre')->where('game_id','=',$id)->pluck('genre_id')->toArray(); // notice pluck to fetch all genre_ids for that game_id
```

In view you need to give genre_id in array to check in `$selectedgenres`

```
@if(in_array($genre->id,$selectedgenres)) // you must pass genre_id here not an object
...... your code
@endif
```

Comment: You're welcome! Please accept the answer by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Comment: I upvoted because I learned something today about `pluck` who replace the `get` :) The only issue is; `pluck` returns a collection and `in_array` does accept only `array`.

Answer (score 0):

Change `$selectedgenres = DB::table('game_genre')->select('genre_id')->where('game_id','=',$id)->get()->toArray();` to `$selectedgenres = DB::table('game_genre')->select('genre_id')->where('game_id','=',$id)->pluck('genre_id');` and `@if(in_array($genre,$selectedgenres))` to `@if(in_array($genre->id,$selectedgenres))`